# Including CSS file in pdf using itextsharp

Tags: vb.net, itext

I am making a pdf file using iTextSharp.

However, the external CSS that is linked in the source HTML does not shown in the PDF.

How can I include the external css file so iTextSharp renders correctly?

```
Dim doc As Document = New Document 
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + _ 
                                          "\ListingDetails.pdf", FileMode.Create)) 

Dim content As String = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/PDFPage.aspx")) 

doc.Open() 

Dim parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(New StringReader(content), Nothing) 

For Each htmlElement As Object In parsedHtmlElements 
   doc.Add(TryCast(htmlElement, IElement)) 
Next 

doc.Close()
```

Comment: Why would you want to? A PDF file will not use CSS internally, so including it in the PDF would do nothing.

Comment: When I am converting html to pdf, the design is not coming as it should be. So how do I apply the css?

Comment: This is where _code_ speaks louder than descriptions. Post your current conversion code so people who know itextsharp can see what exactly you are doing and what can be done with it. Making your description clearer would also help with understanding.

Comment: I have edited your question to make it clearer. Please correct it if I got is wrong. And please add your current code.